# truffle compile with solc 5.0.0 error: solc.compileStandard is not a function

Tags: solc, truffle-compile

Trying to use Solidity `v0.5.0` with Truffle. Starting `v5.0.0` Truffle allows setting `solc` version in `truffle.js`, as per its [docs](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.0#advanced)

I tried both native

```
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "native"
        }
    }
```

with

```
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Linux.g++
```

and solc-js v0.5.0

```
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "0.5.0"
        }
    }
```

all that with Truffle v5:

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.0.0-beta.1 (core: 5.0.0-beta.1)
Solidity v0.4.25 (solc-js)
```

`v0.4.25` here is its default packed solc-js version, not what I use in the project.

But even an empty sample contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Sample {
    constructor() internal {}
}
```

fails to compile:

```
$ truffle compile
TypeError: Error parsing /path/to/project/contracts/Sample.sol: solc.compileStandard is not a function
    at Object.parseImports (/home/etsvigun/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/parser.js:49:1)
    at Object.getImports (/home/etsvigun/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:332:1)
    at Promise.all.then.results (/home/etsvigun/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:305:1)
```

Is there a way to use Solidity v0.5.0 with Truffle already, or doesn't that work yet?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually tried what you're doing, but I noticed a possible misinterpretation of the linked docs. Maybe it will help.

If I'm not mistaken, their "native" is bundled with truffle, and the syntax you used for `solc-js v0.5.0` is for docker containers that I don't *think* you are using.

Did you try?:

```
// Relative or absolute path to an npm installed solc-js
compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: "/Users/axic/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/solc"
  }
}
```

Obviously, the path needs to point to your installed location of the actual binary.

Hope it helps.